# Xamarin Android multiple fonts in same textview

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, fonts, xamarin.android

I'm using Xamarin for an Android App and I have a custom `TypeFace` created as follows:

```
Typeface weatherFont = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Assets, "Weather.ttf");
```

My problem is that I have a `string` that has to be assigned to a `TextView` and I need to set the font of the first 3 characters to the default android font and the remaining to my `weatherFont` Typeface. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Up to API-27, you need a custom `CharacterStyle` subclass to apply a custom `Typeface` to a `Spannable`.

#### Example:

```
var sushiFont = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Assets, "Tastysushi.ttf");
var spannable = new SpannableString("123 = SushiHangover");
spannable.SetSpan (new CustomTypefaceSpan(sushiFont), 3, spannable.Length(), SpanTypes.ExclusiveInclusive);
button.SetText(spannable, TextView.BufferType.Spannable);
```

Or in API-21(+), you can avoid the `SetSpan` char start/end indexing by using `SpannableStringBuilder.Append`:

```
var sushiFont = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Assets, "Tastysushi.ttf");
var spannableString = new SpannableStringBuilder("123");
var spannable = new SpannableString(" = SushiHangover");
spannableString.Append(spannable, new CustomTypefaceSpan(sushiFont), SpanTypes.ExclusiveInclusive);
button.SetText(spannableString, TextView.BufferType.Spannable);
```

And in API-28+, you can directly create spans that directly include a different `Typeface` without using a `CharacterStyle` subclass:

```
spannableString.Append(spannable, new TypefaceSpan(sushiFont), SpanTypes.ExclusiveInclusive);
```

#### CustomTypefaceSpan class

```
public class CustomTypefaceSpan : MetricAffectingSpan
{
    readonly Typeface typeFace;

    public CustomTypefaceSpan(Typeface typeFace)
    {
        this.typeFace = typeFace;
    }

    public override void UpdateDrawState(TextPaint tp)
    {
        tp.SetTypeface(typeFace);
    }

    public override void UpdateMeasureState(TextPaint p)
    {
        p.SetTypeface(typeFace);
    }
}
```

Comment: Very clear and useful explanation! Thank you very much!